# Why won't links be displayed in my dropdown appear but do appear outside of dropdown?

Tags: php, html, laravel, debugging

I want to display `Dashboard` and `Logout` upon clicking the dropdown but with the current code posted below, it's not appearing.

During my attempt to debug, I simply moved `Dashboard` and `Logout` outside of the `div` which indeed did display them but they weren't part of the dropdown.

Why won't my dropdown appear?

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
       <?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?> <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
         <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                        <?php echo e(__('Logout')); ?>

         </a>
          <form id="logout-form" action="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" method="POST" style="display: none;">
              <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
          </form>
     </div>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code, try this one that i made for you. Should work, let me know!

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?>
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><?php echo e(__('Logout')); ?></a></li>
    <form id="logout-form" action="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" method="POST" style="display: none;">
      <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want it on your navbar try this, using **bootstrap 3**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><?php echo e(__('Logout')); ?></a></li>
      <form id="logout-form" action="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you're using **bootstrap 4**, try this one:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><?php echo e(__('Logout')); ?></a>
            <form id="logout-form" action="<?php echo e(route('logout')); ?>" method="POST" style="display: none;">
              <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: hey, thank you for this!  but it doesn't work :( . I actually tried something very similar but to no avail

Comment: You're using bootstrap? I have to know to be able to help you. Try the above if your using bootstrap 3, I updated my answer.

Comment: I updated if you're using bootstrap 4... try it out and let me know

Comment: yeah, I'm using bootstrap 4, should've mentioned that earlier.  The bootstrap 4 solution doesn't work.

Comment: Try that, i updated a full navbar. It's working man, i tried it now on my laravel using bootstrap 4... you're implementing it wrong.